# GCC generates undesired assembly code

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

I'm working on vectorizing loops, and GCC is giving me a hard time.
When I look at the assembly code it generates, I see a lot of strange lines that I would like to get rid of.

For example, with vectorization, I've learnt that you can avoid a lot of extra assembly lines by giving additionnal information to GCC about array alignment.
http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/

Here is my experiment.

```
#define SIZE 1024
void itwillwork (const uint16_t * a, const  uint16_t * b, uint16_t * comp) {
    int i = 0;
    comp[i]=a[i]|b[i];
}
```

Generates simple assembly:

```
.globl  _ZN8Test_LUT7performEv
  23                _ZN8Test_LUT7performEv:
  24                .LFB664:
  25                    .cfi_startproc
  26 0020 488B4710      movq    16(%rdi), %rax
  27 0024 488B4F08      movq    8(%rdi), %rcx
  28 0028 488B5720      movq    32(%rdi), %rdx
  29 002c 0FB700        movzwl  (%rax), %eax
  30 002f 660B01        orw (%rcx), %ax
  31 0032 668902        movw    %ax, (%rdx)
  32 0035 C3            ret
  33                    .cfi_endproc
```

But, even if I was expecting a few extra lines, I am very surprised by what I got after adding a loop :

```
#define SIZE 1024
void itwillwork (const uint16_t * a, const  uint16_t * b, uint16_t * comp) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        comp[i]=a[i]|b[i];
}
```

Generates this assembly with a lot more lines:

```
 233                _Z10itwillworkPKtS0_Pt:
 234                .LFB663:
 235                    .cfi_startproc
 236 0250 488D4210      leaq    16(%rdx), %rax
 237 0254 488D4E10      leaq    16(%rsi), %rcx
 238 0258 4839F0        cmpq    %rsi, %rax
 239 025b 410F96C0      setbe   %r8b
 240 025f 4839CA        cmpq    %rcx, %rdx
 241 0262 0F93C1        setnb   %cl
 242 0265 4108C8        orb %cl, %r8b
 243 0268 743E          je  .L55
 244 026a 4839F8        cmpq    %rdi, %rax
 245 026d 488D4710      leaq    16(%rdi), %rax
 246 0271 0F96C1        setbe   %cl
 247 0274 4839C2        cmpq    %rax, %rdx
 248 0277 0F93C0        setnb   %al
 249 027a 08C1          orb %al, %cl
 250 027c 742A          je  .L55
 251 027e 31C0          xorl    %eax, %eax
 252                    .p2align 4,,10
 253                    .p2align 3
 254                .L57:
 255 0280 F30F6F0C      movdqu  (%rsi,%rax), %xmm1
 255      06
 256 0285 F30F6F04      movdqu  (%rdi,%rax), %xmm0
 256      07
 257 028a 660FEBC1      por %xmm1, %xmm0
 258 028e F30F7F04      movdqu  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax)
 258      02
 259 0293 4883C010      addq    $16, %rax
 260 0297 483D0008      cmpq    $2048, %rax
 260      0000
 261 029d 75E1          jne .L57
 262 029f F3C3          rep ret
 263                    .p2align 4,,10
 264 02a1 0F1F8000      .p2align 3
 264      000000
 265                .L55:
 266 02a8 31C0          xorl    %eax, %eax
 267 02aa 660F1F44      .p2align 4,,10
 267      0000
 268                    .p2align 3
 269                .L58:
 270 02b0 0FB70C06      movzwl  (%rsi,%rax), %ecx
 271 02b4 660B0C07      orw (%rdi,%rax), %cx
 272 02b8 66890C02      movw    %cx, (%rdx,%rax)
 273 02bc 4883C002      addq    $2, %rax
 274 02c0 483D0008      cmpq    $2048, %rax
 274      0000
 275 02c6 75E8          jne .L58
 276 02c8 F3C3          rep ret
 277                    .cfi_endproc
```

Both were compiled with gcc 4.8.4 in release mode, -O2 -ftree-vectorize -msse2.

Can somebody help me get rid of those lines? Or, if it's impossible, can you tell me why they are there ?

**Update :**

I've tried the tricks there http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/, but I get another issue:

```
#define SIZE 1024
void itwillwork (const uint16_t * a, const  uint16_t * b, uint16_t * comp) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        comp[i]=a[i]|b[i];
}
```

A few assembly lines are generated for this function, I get it.
But when I call this function from somewhere else :

```
itwillwork(a,b,c);
```

There is no call instruction : the long list of instructions of "itwillwork" (the same as above) are used directly.
Am I missing something ? (the "extra lines" are the problem, not the inline call)

Comment: A nice idea is to paste the assembly code in your question, rather than having to go to a pastebin site. I don't understand why you put high level code in your question, but not the assembly.

Comment: Why do you think having so many more lines is a bad thing?  If the optimized code runs fast, do you care about code size?  But also, WHAT did you try with `restrict` (post that version of the C++ code).  The asm code look to me like the compiler is not aware of restrict pointers (especially `comp`) and would be more efficient if it were.

Comment: I tried to paste the assembly code here, but it wasn't readable at all (for some reason, no line feed).

Comment: The compiler isn't calling your code because it has determined that the code is small (and simple) enough to inline.

Comment: I tried the tricks I mentioned again, and it worked, at least for the function's body. If another function calls "itwillwork", a lot of assembly lines are generated there (in the caller). They are similar to the ones posted above. I guess I did it wrong the first time, but there is still an issue (the "extra lines", not the inline call).

(And thanks for putting the assembly code, I don't know why I didn't manage to do it in the first place ...)

Comment: The reason the compiler produces a lot of code for this function mostly comes from two problems: 1. Pointer aliasing, 2. alignment. You can promise the compiler that you don't alias your pointers with `restrict`, and gcc has a builtin to promise that the pointers are aligned with `__buitin_assume_aligned()`.

Comment: It looks like the compiler added the loop twice, once with SIMD instructions and once without. My guess is that this is because the alignment requirement for SIMD instructions are different from the alignment requirements for scalar types and it needs to decide which path to take at runtime.

Comment: ..or the compiler cannot assume you have the SIMD instruction set. Check your compiler flags.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : OP did mention he was using `-O2 -ftree-vectorize -msse2` for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting *"weird"* code because GCC cannot make assumptions about the alignment of your pointers so you can see that it is first performing an alignment test to determine whether it can take the fast path and do 128 bits at a time, or the slow path and do 16 bits at a time.

Additionally, the reason you are finding the code repeated is because the compiler is applying an inlining optimisation. You could disable this with the `__attribute((noinline))` spec but if performance is your goal, let the compiler inline it.

If you specify the `__restrict` keyword then the compiler will only generate the fast-path code: https://goo.gl/g3jUfQ

**However**, this does not mean the compiler is going to magically take care of alignment for you so take care of what you pass to the function.

Comment: I tried this, it worked well, thank you !
Yet, I tried using a class (variables are now attributes and functions are now methods, see https://goo.gl/x7aP6W - the code isn't supposed to do anything interesting).
As you can see, this is compiled "correctly". But as soon as I split this code into a ".h" and a ".cpp" files, I get the extra lines mentioned earlier. Any idea why ?

Comment: what does the prototype and definition look like.